# Hibernate./JPA native bulk insert with on duplicate key update issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have used this function to generate bulk insert to MySQL 5.7 with insert or update

```
private String bulkInsertQuery(List<ProducDetails> productDetailsList){
    StringBuilder prodBatchInsert=new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO product_details(prod_id, prod) VALUES ");
    StringBuilder prodBatchInsertOnDuplicateKey=new StringBuilder(" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE prod=VALUES(prod)");
    productDetailsList.forEach((ProductDetails row)->{
        prodBatchInsert.append("(");
        prodBatchInsert.append("\""+row.getProdId()+"\"");
        prodBatchInsert.append(",");
        prodBatchInsert.append("\""+row.getProd()+"\"");
        prodBatchInsert.append(")");
        prodBatchInsert.append(",");
    });
    String insertSql=prodBatchInsert.toString();
    return insertSql.substring(0,insertSql.length()-1).concat(prodBatchInsertOnDuplicateKey.toString());
}

Query query=entityManager.createQuery(bulkInsertQuery(productDetailsList));
            query.executeUpdate();
```

initially, I used single quotes but it fails due to this type of data product names like ABC'S FOOD which contained single quotes, then I switched to the above double quotes

> I want to know if there is a way to resolve this or use parameterized queries to bulk insert on update duplicate keys.

Comment: Hibernate does support batch inserts. Please look here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update

Comment: yes but I want on duplicate key update too...it doesn't work that way

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@SQLInsert` for this purpose to use batch inserts. See [Hibernate Transactions and Concurrency Using attachDirty (saveOrUpdate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754720/hibernate-transactions-and-concurrency-using-attachdirty-saveorupdate/64764412#64764412)

Comment: Check the example in the other stack overflow post :)

Comment: i'm getting this issue now javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Comment: Why are you trying to persist the same object multiple times with the same persistence context? Try to de-duplicate your list first before running this process.