# Spring data batch saveAll handling exceptions

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring boot application where I am doing a lot of inserts by collecting data from kafka. I wish to use saveAll batch insert for increasing performance. But there are few datas that would be considered duplicates and I am updating them whenever catching DataIntegrityViolationException in my code. With batch insert, is there a way to catch this exception for each data that is duplicate and handle that with the do update code?

Comment: how do you determine if something is duplicate? What column do you check?

Comment: I have unique constraint on two columns that throws Exception when broken

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@SQLInsert` annotation of Hibernate to change the way the inserts are done. See [Hibernate Transactions and Concurrency Using attachDirty (saveOrUpdate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754720/hibernate-transactions-and-concurrency-using-attachdirty-saveorupdate/64764412#64764412) for details.