# Is there any way to handle org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException for unique constraint in saveAll of CrudRepository of Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I want to save multiple objects at once and for that I am using CrudRepository's saveAll method in spring boot. But object have one property with unique constraint in mysql. So when I tried to saveAll method it is showing me duplication entry exception i.e. org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException.
I want to save all others objects which doesn't get exception of duplicate entry.
Can anyone having this type of requirement? Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: Filter before saving?

Comment: @yoni for filtering I have to check each record with each record present in database. For large number of records it will take time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using saveAll method, use below

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            try {
               save(list.get(i));
            } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
            continue;
         }
      }
```

Comment: Is it possible to catch exception with saveAll method? Actually, I have large number of records which I want to save at once. Single record save at once will take more time right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754720/hibernate-transactions-and-concurrency-using-attachdirty-saveorupdate/64764412#64764412 - Check this out, It might resolve your problem..