# Nested transactions in Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot application with persistence using Hibernate/JPA.

I am using transactions to manage my database persistence, and I am using the [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) annotation to define the methods that should execute transactionally.

I have three main levels of transaction granularity when persisting:

1. Batches of entities to be persisted
2. Single entities to be persisted
3. Single database operations that persist an entity

Therefore, you can imagine that I have three levels of nested transactions when thinking about the whole persistence flux.

The interaction between between levels 2 and 3 works transparently as I desire because without specifying any [Propagation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) behaviour for the transaction, the default is the [REQUIRED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRED) behaviour, and so the entire entity (level 2) is rolled back because level 3 will support the transaction defined in level 2.

However, the problem is that I need an interaction between 1 and 2 that is slightly different. I need an entity to be rolled back individually if an error were to occur, but I wouldn't like the entire batch to be rolled back. That being said, I need to specify a propagation behavior in the level 2 annotation `@Transactional(propagation = X)` that follows these requirements.

I've tried [`REQUIRES_NEW`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW) but that doesn't work because it commits some of the entities from level 2 even if the whole batch had to be rolled back, which can also happen.

The behaviour that seems to fit the description better is [`NESTED`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NESTED), but that is not accepted when using Spring and Hibernate JPA, [see here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-transaction-propagation) for more information.

This last link offers alternatives for the NESTED type, but I would like to know if NESTED would've really solved my problem, or if there was another behaviour that suited the job better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess NESTED would roughly do what you want but I would question if this really is necessary. I don't know what you are trying to do or what the error condition is, but maybe you can get rid of the error condition by using some kind of `WHERE` clause or an UPSERT statement: [Hibernate Transactions and Concurrency Using attachDirty (saveOrUpdate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754720/hibernate-transactions-and-concurrency-using-attachdirty-saveorupdate/64764412#64764412)

Comment: Actually I don't want to get rid of the error condition. You see, the errors on level 2 are well known "business" errors, so I do want to catch them and rollback a single entity. On the other hand, errors on level 1 are unexpected, so I would like to log them and rollback the whole batch. It would be nice to have two "levels of rollback granularity", but I think the only propagation behaviour that does it is NESTED, but that my JPA does not  support, so I have to settle for just one level of rollback adjustment. I was wondering if there is a workaround that still uses Spring's Transactions.

Comment: None that I know of. The question is, whether these errors have to be database errors i.e. data validation can to some extent occur without causing exceptions on the JDBC level, since a JDBC exception requires a TX rollback.

Comment: And by the way, here a nice article about possible issues with save points which might help you reconsider your approach: https://postgres.ai/blog/20210831-postgresql-subtransactions-considered-harmful